# jquery validation with datepicker, problems with highlight

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two fields on my form. one is plain input for name and the other is powered with 'vitalets bootstrap datepicker'. I decided to use jquery validation plug in on it so when the first one 'name' is left blank it gets red, and for second 'date_birth' if in it stays default value it also turns red. So you gotta insert a name and you gotta pick some date than default one.

I've added a errorPlacement and success rules which are doing as I described. But problem is on my 'date_birth' field. it gets red when you do not choose some other date but, second time, after submit if you choose some other date which is correct. It does not turns green as the above 'name' field....

Here is situation in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/5xgfm/

html:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="gold_form" method='post' action='/start_ajax/addgold/'>
 <fieldset>
    <span class="label-f">Name</span>
    <input type="text" class="span4" id="name" name="name">
    </br>
    <span class="label-f">Date of birth</span>
    <div class="input-append date notification" id="date_birth_picker" data-date="1980-01-01" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="1980-01-01" readonly="" id="date_birth" name="date_birth">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

script:

```
//datepicker
$(function(){
            window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();

            $('#date_birth_picker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                weekStart: 1,
            });

        });


//validation
$().ready(function() {
                jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element){
                    switch (element.value){
                        case $(element).prop("defaultValue"):
                        if (element.name == "date_birth") return false;
                        break;
                        default: return true; 
                        break;
                        }
                        });


                $("#gold_form").validate(
                    {
                    rules:{date_birth: "required defaultInvalid",
                           name: "required",
                           family_name: "required"
                          },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').addClass("invalid");
    },
    success: function(error) {
        $("#gold_form").find('.valid').removeClass("invalid").addClass("success");
    },
                    });
                });
```

css:

```
@import   url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.error {
float: none; color: red !important; padding-left: .5em;    
vertical-align: top; 
}
.invalid {
border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.success{
border: 1px solid green !important;
}
```

Am I missing something or what? You can freely edit my jsfiddle.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to re-check the validity of the date whenever the datepicker changes it, by hand.

So after your datepicker is created, add a `changeDate` event that runs the `valid` method:

```
 $('#date_birth_picker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                weekStart: 1,
 }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if($('#date_birth').valid()){
       $('#date_birth').removeClass('invalid').addClass('success');   
    }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xgfm/2/

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, after selecting a date, datepicker() loses focus of the date field and none of the validator plugins can see the date input field as filled (valid).
As a conclusion, a simple .focus() does the trick.

```
$('#datefield').datepicker({
  //datepicker methods and settings here
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
  $(this).focus();    
});
```

I have also posted this answer to this post [Bootstrap datepicker and bootstrap validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537003/bootstrap-datepicker-and-bootstrap-validator/36130899#36130899)

Comment: `on('changeDate', function (e) { $(this).blur(); $(this).focus();   })` works for me

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below example which is programmatically correct.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**Explanation**

On change of date, the datepicker method will trigger the jquery `valid()` method which will validate the field. If the field is valid it will remove the error message.