# Bootstrap datepicker and bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am using the bootstrap datepicker from [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and the bootstrap validator from [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/). Also I am using bootstrap v3.1.1.

After selecting a date from datepicker the validator does not react. It works just when I use the keyboard to enter a date.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST"> 
   <div class="col-lg-3">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input name="endDate" type="text" class="datepicker form-control">
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

In .js file I added:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
)};
```

and for validators:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            endDate: {
                validators: {
                    date: {
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        message: 'The format is dd/mm/yyyy'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field can not be empty'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you tell us which are those two plugins you are using? The validator can be easy to guess but it will help your post if you mentioned the two plugins.

Comment: For validation I use bootstrapValidator.min.js version v0.5.0, built on 2014-07-14 and for datepicker I use bootstrap-datepicker.js version 3.1.1 and I use jquery 1.10.2.

Comment: I meant to give the links of the plugins pages. E.g. for validation are you using this http://bootstrapvalidator.com/? For the datepicker, are you using this http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?

Comment: Yes, I use the datepicker and the validators from the two links mentioned by you. And I use a datetimepicker from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ which I have the same problem. Thanks for yours answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using BootstrapValidator with Bootstrap-datetimepicker or Bootstrap-datepicker, you should revalidate the date field.

So you should add this:

1) using with bootstrap-datetimepicker :

```
$('.date')
    .on('dp.change dp.show', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date when user change it
        $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'endDate');
});
```

2) using with bootstrap-datepicker :

```
$('.datepicker')
    .on('changeDate show', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date when user change it
        $('#myForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'endDate');
});
```

See the [datetimepicker example](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/api/#revalidate-field-examples) for more information.

Comment: I have an issue that ``data.bv.isValid()`` is always ``false``

Comment: @YouYou please create a new question or create an issue on the proper repository at https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/issues/new

Answer (score 5):

Somehow, after selecting a date, datepicker() loses focus of the date field and none of the validator plugins can see the date input field as filled (valid).
As a conclusion, a simple .focus() does the trick.

```
$('#datefield').datepicker({
  //datepicker methods and settings here
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
  $(this).focus();    
});
```

Comment: boy, you're simple yet clever solution saved me a major case of heart burn! Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. Adding the .focus() seemed to solve the issue but it really didn't - the invalid class was being removed w/ it but the validate plugin still considered the field as invalid!

Comment: @RogerDodger, which validator plugin are you using?

Comment: The one at jqueryvalidation.org - what fixed it was the solution provided by @Sparky on another SO thread, instead of $(this).focus() , I used $(this).valid(). That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Above accepted answer didn't work me. What worked for me was very simple.

```
$('#datefield').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
         $('#datefield').focus();
         $('#anyotherfield').focus();
         $('#datefield').focus();             
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For most of cases answers above should work, but  if eventually anythose answers ain't working for you, could try this too:

```
$('.datepicker').change(function () {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).blur();
    });
```

Main idea in this script is to force validations by "setting" and after "unsetting" the focus. I understand that would be similar to emulate the normal events that permit to run validations.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('[name="StartDate"]').datepicker({
            weekStart: 1,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {

            if ($('[name="StartDate"]').val() == '' || typeof 
    $('[name="StartDate"]').val() == "undefined") {                
                $('[name="EndDate"]').val('').datepicker('setStartDate', null);                
            }
            else {
                $('[name="EndDate"]').val('').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
                $('[name="EndDate"]').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
                startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
                $('[name="EndDate"]').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
                $('[name="EndDate"]').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
                $('[name="EndDate"]').val('').datepicker('update', '');
            }
        });

        $('[name="StartDate"]').blur(function (selected) {
            if ($('[name="EndDate"]').val() != '' && $('[name="StartDate"]').val() == '' || typeof $('[name="StartDate"]').val() == "undefined") {                
                $('[name="StartDate"]').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
                $('[name="StartDate"]').val('').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
                $('[name="EndDate"]').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
                $('[name="EndDate"]').val('').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
            }
        });

     $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        }).datepicker();
```

Comment: Aey, mind adding some description.. See How [do I write a good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) answer, [Welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to Stack Overflow !

Answer (score -2):

You must also include the latest validation cdn into your project:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js