# How to accept only date as input field value for bootstrap datepicker in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-datepicker

### html

```
                 <form name="eventInformation" id="eventInformation"><label class="required"> Occurence Date </label>
                     <p class="input-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="formData_EventDetails.eventOccurDate"
                              is-open="popup[0].opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" required/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(0)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                    </p>

                <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                          <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary ebtn"
                                  ng-disabled="eventInformation.$invalid"
                                  ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
                      </div>
</form>
```

### javascript

```
                        $scope.format = 'yyyy/MM/dd';


                        $scope.dateOptions = {
                            formatYear : 'yy',
                            startingDay : 1
                        };

                        $scope.popup = [];
                        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            $scope.popup[i] = {
                                opened : false
                            };
                        }

                        $scope.open = function(i) {
                            $scope.popup[i].opened = true;
                        };
```

I have bootstrap datepicker element which i am trying to only accept date as input, but it accepts all kinds of inputs i.e. string, numbers etc. How can i limit so it only takes date as input

Comment: Possible duplicate [Bootstrap datepicker and bootstrap validator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25644924/1260204)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a input text box, You can't restrict the user to enter invalid characters(default behavior).

But you can stop the model update operation, when the user provides wrong date (for that you need to setup following attributes on your input element)

```
ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: false}"
```

Comment: another weird thing to notice is that submit button is disabled when i input some string value, which means ng-disabled="eventInformation.$invalid" is true for some reason and is recognizing as date field