# How Do I add a invalidation error message to bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-datepicker

How do I add a validation message to my date picker? Currently it works but it gives no response to the user so I want the message to read "you must be over age 13 to sign up."

HTML

```
<!--  Birth Date -->
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group floating-label col-md-6">
      <label>Date of Birth</label>
      <input id= "date" type="text" name="date" 
      class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required=""/>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]');
        var container=$('.form-horizontal').length>0 ? $('.form-horizontal').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            endDate: '-13y',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: "top",
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537003/bootstrap-datepicker-and-bootstrap-validator/36130899

Comment: I actually checked there. It is not exactly my issue. I have the validator working but I do not know how to fire off a error message in BS datepicker. The op of the other thread was trying to combite bs3 and date picker. Im actually using bs 4